# Domain Pointing to www.domain.com:8888

Tags: localhost, domain

I have uploaded my website through FTP and database to mysql, the domain is now showing www.domain.com:8888 and seems to be pointing to my local host still.

how do i redirect this to tell it to now locate the active domain online, what file do I need to correct?

Any help appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving a site is more than moving the database. And it is more than updating the wp-options table's URLs (although that is important). You also have to change any references to the old URL in the database.

I use a plugin called "[Better Search and Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)" to update the URLs in the database. (There are other similar plugins; this is the one I prefer. YMMV.)

But I also use my own procedure, developed over many site moves, to properly move a site from one place to another, whether that be a development-to-live move, or a move to a new hosting place.

The process is too long to post here. Here's the link: https://securitydawg.com/moving-a-wordpress-site/ . If you follow all parts of that procedure, you will have a successful site move.

Comment: really appreciate this information. will try it out and let you know the results.

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer works for you, then a 'checkmark' is appreciated (standard practice). This lets others that come across your question that the answer worked for you, and may help them with a similar problem.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks again.

To note, the update of the options file was certainly the first step, this pulled my site online. The next step was certainly using the Better Search and Replace plugin which worked a charm to replace my localhost:8888 address and replaced it with my domain.com address for all my links that required it. Theres a few bugs here and there but nothing a boot can't fix! :) 

Thanks for your answer, your link to the longer explanation is going in my bookmarks for future use!

Answer (score -1):

You need to change wordpress address and site address in database:

wp_options table - siteurl , home